# Python Blob Storage read failing with Azure AD RBAC - no attribute 'signed session'

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

The problem summary: Python read from Blob Store using Azure SDK for Python fails on BlockBlobService.get_blob_to_path, with  error the the RBAC client I'm using has no attribute called 'signed session', after I've authenticated to Azure AD.

The detail:

I've got read access (as a THIRD PARTY) to an Azure Blob Storage account - using the Azure Active Directory RBAC (Roles Based Access Control). The owners of the Blob store have granted me the role of Storage Blob Data Reader.

The detailed examples I find online for connecting from Python to read from a Blob store use the account_name and account_key parameters - but I do not have those credentials as I do not own the store itself.

I thus found how to use RBAC to connect to Azure - however the read operation itself seems to fail - although I imagine my problem is actually in the step to create the BlockBlobService.

I've created a simplified script to pull a sample of files from the store - based on the files I know I need to download. I seem to be able to connect to Azure Active Directory (disconnecting internet connection confirms failure), but once the read is executed, after some time (~30 seconds), an error is generated as shown below.

Naturally - the redacted sections have the correct credentials / details in my code:

```
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
    from azure.storage.blob import ContainerPermissions
    from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
    from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials

    print('Connecting to Azure Active Directory')
    credentials = UserPassCredentials(
                'myname@email.com',      # Your user
                'zzzzz',          # Your password
                resource="https://graph.windows.net"
        )

    tenant_id = "zzzz"

    graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
        credentials,
        tenant_id
    )

    AccountName = "account_name"
    imagesContainer = "container_name"

    ## Connect to the Azure Block Blob service using the GraphRBAC
    print('Connecting to Azure Block Blob Service')
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=AccountName, token_credential=graphrbac_client)
```

All the above seems to run correctly, without any errors or exceptions. However, as soon as I run the code below - then I get the error below:

```
    block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(imagesContainer, AzureFilename, newFileName)
```

```
Exception has occurred: azure.common.AzureException
'GraphRbacManagementClient' object has no attribute 'signed_session'
  File "C:\zzz\PullUnsortedImagesFromAzure.py", line 138, in <module>
    block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(imagesContainer, AzureFilename, newFileName)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

What is interesting is that in Windows Explorer, I can actually see the file being created - but it doesn't actually get pulled from Blob store.

I'm really no expert when it comes to AD - so I'm guessing, but I imagine the issue is probably originating from:

```
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=AccountName, token_credential=graphrbac_client)
```

I would be extremely grateful if anyone could help point out what I should be doing...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps as below to authenticate an application to access the storage blob.

1.[Register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app) in Azure portal.

Click the app you just registered.
[image]
Click Settings->click keys->input a description for the key->click save. The value of the key is client secret.

[image]
2.[Grant the permissions to your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

3.access storage resource

```
import adal
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService,
    ContainerPermissions,
)
from azure.storage.common import (
    TokenCredential
)

RESOURCE = "https://storage.azure.com/"
clientId = "***"
clientSecret = "***="
tenantId = "***"
authority_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId

print(authority_url)
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)

token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    RESOURCE,
    clientId,
    clientSecret)
print(token)

tokenCre = TokenCredential(token["accessToken"])

blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name="***", token_credential=tokenCre)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, Tony - I unfortunately don't have permissions to add Applications or grant the permissions in the Storage container - but I've asked the owner to do so, so hopefully will come right... I'll post back once I've tested!

Comment: @Brian You are welcome. Just let me know if you need further assistance regarding this.

Comment: @Brian Hi Brian, how it is going now?

Comment: hi - the admin has just added the application, but I'm having no joy. I find that using the Application ID, ADAL does connect to storage, however the client secret seems a mystery to me - I've tried the ObjectID, however I keep getting the ADAL error that "AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided. I've created a test application on my own Azure - but cannot see where the client secret comes from. In your code above, what does the clientSecret refer to and where do I find it? Many thanks!

Comment: @Brian I have updated the answer, you can check that.

Comment: Hi Tony - unfortunately it really hasn't gone smoothly. I did figure out how to add keys based on the app we had added - and the authentication worked perfectly (i.e. context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)  and tokenCre = TokenCredential(token["accessToken"]) and block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, token_credential=tokenCre) all worked perfectly.

Comment: What however is now giving an error is the command to do the actual blob retrieval - block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(imagesContainer, AzureFilename, newFileName) fails with the error Exception=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. ErrorCode: Authorization Permission Mismatch. We had added access on blob and container level so we really didn't have a clue what else to do

Comment: Hi Tony - one more update - it is magically working now - I'm not kidding. I've confirmed NO change on the Azure setup side by the Blob storage + AD owner, and no change on the Python script. I can only think that because the Blob Storage Reader has been in preview until recently, that there was a problem earlier when trying it. I'm happy to accept your answer above as correct - it's working great now - thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)